# Adding custom Bulk Actions

Tags: hooks, actions, bulk

I have been looking around for ways to add custom Bulk Actions to the categories page. Most of them say that it is impossible to do it in a clean way, because of the lack of a hook for this.

Most of the solutions include using JS in the client side to add the options though DOM manipulation. While this works, it is still quite an ugly solution.

Most of the articles I have been reading are about 2 year old, so I was wondering since then to the present a new hook or solution has been added to this problem, to have a more up-to-date solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's still not really doable in a clean way.  You can see the latest about this here in this [trac ticket #16031](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16031)

I just checked the source and the filter is still basically the same.